# Rounding Mechanism to nearest 0.05

Tags: php, rounding

I would like to solve rounding mechanism by using php4,5.2 and below (not 5.3)
Currently I am doing 0.05 rounding, something like this page:

http://www.bnm.gov.my/index.php?ch=209&pg=657&ac=568

```
before rounding | after rounding

          89.90 | 89.90

          89.91 | 89.90

          89.92 | 89.90

          89.93 | 89.95

          89.94 | 89.95

          89.95 | 89.95

          89.96 | 89.95

          89.97 | 89.95

          89.98 | 90.00

          89.99 | 90.00
```

I try to use string to split it out and manually do adding, but not really a good solution, hoping here can find someone to solve it.

Comment: function rndfunc($x){
  return round($x * 2, 1) / 2;
}
it's work! Thanks a lot Mauris

Comment: If one answer solved your problem, please click the big tick next to their answer.

Comment: @Shiro - yep like e.c.ho said, put a tick so that when others come to this question, they know the answer.

Comment: opps, I am sry forget to put a big tick there. Thanks a lot guys~

Answer (score 18, accepted):

use this function

```
function rndfunc($x){
  return round($x * 2, 1) / 2;
}
```

Comment: You end up with only one number after the decimal if it ends in zero (0).

Comment: sprintf('%0.2f', rndfunc($x));

Comment: it works for me in WordPress woocommerce price filter. Thank you so much 

add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_excluding_tax', 'round_price_product', 10, 1 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_including_tax', 'round_price_product', 10, 1 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_tax_round', 'round_price_product', 10, 1);
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price', 'round_price_product', 10, 1);

function round_price_product( $price ) {
        
    return round($price * 2, 1) / 2;
}

Answer (score 13):

Conceptually, the procedure can be done as:

1. Divide by 0.05

   - or multiply by (1 / 0.05)
2. Round to nearest integer
3. Multiply by 0.05

Comment: I think this should have been the accepted answer... As it will allow you to basically round to any number you desire.

Want to round by 0.005? no problem. Or even 0.00002? Sure!

    round($price / $min_size) * $min_size

$price can be any float
min_size is the smallest number possible (eg: 0.005 or 0.000002)

Simple, but brilliant!

Comment: Yes, this is an awesome math hack!

Answer (score 1):

You basically want to map values to a grid.  The grid is defined as `a multiple of .05`.  In general, you need to find the multiplicands your value lies between.

What *isn't* in the table are the negative numbers.  You need to decide on whether to round away from zero (symmetrical) or always in the same direction (i.e. positive).

code:

```
$step = .05;
$multiplicand = floor( $value / $step );
$rest = $value % $step ;
if( $rest > $step/2 ) $multiplicand++; // round up if needed
$roundedvalue = $step*$multiplicand;
```

Comment: There's a division by zero on the `$rest = ` line.

Comment: @e.c.ho: how can that be if `$step` isn't zero?

Comment: Ran the code and that's the error message that came flying back.

Comment: This will not always round UP, try e.g. value of 11.25 -- this code will result in .55 whereas correct answer is 0.5625 => 0.60. To always round up, you can simply do: ceiling($value/$step)*$step

Answer (score 0):

Multiply by two, then round, then divide by two.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:-

$input1 = 24.05;

$things = abs($input * 20 ); // 481 ".05"s

$tenpcnt = abs($things / 10); // 48 ".05"s

$ouput = $tenpcnt / 20;

echo $ouput;   //   2.40

Answer (score 0):

```
function round5Sen ($value) { 

    return number_format(round($value*20,0)/20,2,'.','');
} 

echo round5Sen(155.13);
echo "\n";
echo round5Sen(155.12);
echo "\n";
echo round5Sen(155.0);
echo "\n";
echo round5Sen(155.18);
echo "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are more elegant solutions, but this appears to suit the task:

```
<?php

// setup test
$start_num = 89.90;
$iterations = 10;

// loop through test numbers
for ($i = 0; $i < $iterations; $i++) {
  nickleRound($start_num + (0.01 * $i));
  echo "\n\n";
}

//
function nickleRound($num) {
  $p = 0.05;
  echo "\n" . 'p= ' . $p;

  $num = round($num, 2);
  echo "\n" . 'num= ' . $num;

  $r = ($num / $p);
  echo "\n" . 'r= ' . $r;

  $r2 = ceil($r) - $r;  
  echo "\n" . 'r2= ' . $r2;

  $a = round($num, 1);
  if (($r2 > 0) && ($r2 < 0.5)) {
    $a = $a + 0.05; 
  }
  echo "\n" . 'a= ' . $a;
}
```

Comment: Mauris wins - I figured there was a simpler method. (-:

Answer (score 0):

Expanding a little on @xtofl to allow for more precise steps (not technically required for this question)

```
    $step         = 0.0005;
    $multiplicand = floor($value / $step);
    $rest         = fmod($value, $step);

    $value = $step * $multiplicand;

    if ($rest > $step / 2) {
        $value += $step;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Round to nearest 0.05
echo round ($number * 20, 0) / 20;

//Round Up to nearest 0.05
echo ceil ($number * 20) / 20;

//Round Down to nearest 0.05
echo floor ($number * 20) / 20;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @mauris for the solution to solve my problem on Malaysia GST rounding mechanism. It also works in SQL.

DECLARE @tempTable AS TABLE(Number Decimal(20,4));

INSERT INTO @tempTable VALUES (89.90),(89.91),(89.92),(89.93),(89.94),(89.95),(89.96),(89.97),(89.98),(89.99)

SELECT Number, round(Number * 2, 1) / 2 AS 'Rounded' FROM @tempTable

Answer (score 0):

PHP has the function round() for the PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7, PHP 8

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php