# Round cart total and subtotal decimals off to nearest 5 unit in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, rounding, cart, hook-woocommerce

I have been working on the cart value roundup to the nearest value and created a function but it roundups the complete value.

What am I doing wrong?

```php
//round cart total up to nearest dollar
add_filter( 'woocommerce_calculated_total', 'custom_calculated_total' );
function custom_calculated_total( $total ) {
    $total = round( $total );
    return ceil($total / 5) * 5;
}
```

---

If I have the values `44.24` I want to output as `44.25` and if I have the value as `44.28` then the output should be as `44.30`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all you will need to use the `woocommerce_cart_subtotal` filter hook in addition to the `woocommerce_calculated_total` filter hook.
Otherwise your subtotal will deviate from the total, which seems weird

Then you can use 1 of the answers from: [Rounding Mechanism to nearest 0.05](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1592352/11987538)

So you get:

```php
function rnd_func( $x ) {
    return round( $x * 2, 1 ) / 2;
}

function filter_woocommerce_cart_subtotal( $subtotal, $compound, $cart ) {
    // Get cart subtotal
    $round = rnd_func( $cart->subtotal );
    
    // Use wc_price(), for the correct HTML output
    $subtotal = wc_price( $round );

    return $subtotal;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_subtotal', 'filter_woocommerce_cart_subtotal', 10, 3 );

// Allow plugins to filter the grand total, and sum the cart totals in case of modifications.
function filter_woocommerce_calculated_total( $total, $cart ) {    
    return rnd_func( $total );
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_calculated_total', 'filter_woocommerce_calculated_total', 10, 2 );
```